# Bring 'offline node' online script

Tags: python, jenkins

So I was wondering if it's possible to create a script that checks in a node is `offline` and if it is it should bring it back `online`. The login used should be by `username` and `token`.

I'm talking about a script that triggers this button on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: the scripted action for that button is [`.doToggleOffline`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/slaves/SlaveComputer.html):
`Jenkins.instance.getNode('Node-Name').getComputer().doToggleOffline(offlineMessage)`

*I knew I had dealt with this before but did not recall the [`cliOnline()`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#cliOnline()) command. In looking it up I noticed it was deprecated. Turns out I used a different approach.*

Can't say I fully understand the possible states and their applicability as it's not well-documented. The table shown below is as reflected in the **Build Executor Status** side panel; the `/computer` **Manage nodes and clouds** table will only show the computer w/ or w/o **X**.

```
// Connect (Launch) / Disconnect Node
Jenkins.instance.getNode('Node-Name').getComputer().launch()
Jenkins.instance.getNode('Node-Name').getComputer().disconnect()

// Make this node temporarily offline (true) / Bring this node back online (false)
Jenkins.instance.getNode('Node-Name').getComputer().setTemporarilyOffline(false, OfflineCause cause)

// Availabiltiy: Accepting Tasks (true) / Not Accepting Tasks (false)
Jenkins.instance.getNode('Node-Name').getComputer().setAcceptingTasks(true)
```

[image: Node States]

The [isAcceptingTasks()](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/slaves/SlaveComputer.html#setAcceptingTasks(boolean)) JavaDoc explains this as:

> Needed to allow agents programmatic suspension of task scheduling that
> does not overlap with being offline.

The [isTemporarilyOffline()](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#isTemporarilyOffline()) JavaDoc elaborates:

> Returns true if this node is marked temporarily offline by the user.
> In contrast, `isOffline()` represents the actual online/offline state

JavaDoc for [isOffline](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#isOffline()) (both [Temporarily](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#isTemporarilyOffline()) and Disconnected),  [setTemporarilyOffline](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#isAcceptingTasks()) and [setAcceptingTasks](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#setTemporarilyOffline(boolean,hudson.slaves.OfflineCause)).

---

But, after all that, turns out **there's one more option**:

```
def offlineMessage = "I did it"
Jenkins.instance.getNode('Node-Name').getComputer().doToggleOffline(offlineMessage)
```

And if you run that from the groovy console, it toggles the state (so I guess you check state first):
[image: Toggle Off-line]

And run it again:

[image: Toggle Again]

---

My experience relates to: [JENKINS-59283 - Use distinct icon for disconnected and temporarily offline computers](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-59283) / [PR-4195](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/4195) and having brought agents on-line when they should have been unavailable per schedule (**Node Availability**: Bring this agent online according to a schedule) so nothing ran. The PR was to introduce a yellow X for the Not Accepting but On-line condition, but the icons have now changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply make temporarily disabled nodes online you can use the following script to do this.

```
def jenkinsNodes = Jenkins.instance.getNodes()
def nodeLabelToMatch = "label1"
  for(def node: jenkinsNodes) {
      if(node.labelString.contains(nodeLabelToMatch)) {
        if (node.getComputer().isOffline()){  
            node.getComputer().cliOnline()
        }
      }
  }
```

**Update : Full Pipeline**

The script is written in groovy

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def jenkinsNodes = Jenkins.instance.getNodes()
                    def nodeLabelToMatch = "label1"
                      for(def node: jenkinsNodes) {
                          if(node.labelString.contains(nodeLabelToMatch)) {
                            if (node.getComputer().isOffline()){  
                                node.getComputer().cliOnline()
                            }
                          }
                      }
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

**Non-Depricated Method.**

If you look at [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/a351a55418e69a01bf6ffa47fa8130171f6012da/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Computer.java#L560) depricated method, it simply calls a non depricated [method](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/a351a55418e69a01bf6ffa47fa8130171f6012da/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Computer.java#L705) `setTemporarilyOffline(boolean temporarilyOffline, OfflineCause cause)`. So instead of using `cliOnline()` you can use `setTemporarilyOffline`. Check the following.

```
node.getComputer().setTemporarilyOffline(false, null)
```

Some proper code with a proper cause. The cause is not really needed when setting the node online though.

```
import hudson.slaves.OfflineCause.UserCause

def jenkinsNodes = Jenkins.instance.getNodes()
  for(def node: jenkinsNodes) {
      if (node.getComputer().isTemporarilyOffline()){  
           node.getComputer().setTemporarilyOffline(false, null)
      }
  }
```

Setting to temporarily offline

```
UserCause cause =  new UserCause(User.current(), "This is a automated process!!")
node.getComputer().setTemporarilyOffline(true, cause)
```

Comment: cCliOnline is [deprecated](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#cliOnline())

Comment: So do you want me to run this as a script in a Jenkins job or? and how do I choose a specific Node with this methode?

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup You can either execute the above in the Jenkins Script console or within a Job itself. I updated the answer to check the Node name by the labels.

Comment: @IanW how do I use the non deprecated? node.getComputer().OnlineNodeCommand() doesn't work

Comment: @ycr you have some parentheses errors and the function labelstring is not right, it should be `if (node.getNodeName().contains(nodeLabelToMatch))` and `getComputer()` should be `toComputer()`. I made the script work now. Do you know how to use the  `.OnlineNodeCommand()` instead of `cliOnline()`